# Как соединить таблицы и добавить столбец в полученную таблицу?

Tags: postgresql

Есть две таблицы sch.t1:

| "name" | "spec" | "sal" | "from" | "to" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Имя1" | "Специалист1" | 10000 | "2020-01-01" | "2020-01-31" |
| "Имя1" | "Специалист1" | 12000 | "2020-02-01" | "2020-02-29" |
| "Имя1" | "Специалист1" | 13500 | "2020-03-01" | "2020-03-31" |
| "Имя1" | "Специалист1" | 15000 | "2020-04-01" | "2020-04-30" |
| "Имя1" | "Специалист1" | 15500 | "2020-05-01" | "2020-05-31" |
| "Имя1" | "Специалист1" | 16000 | "2020-06-01" | "2020-06-30" |
| "Имя1" | "Специалист2" | 17000 | "2020-07-01" | "2020-07-31" |
| "Имя1" | "Специалист2" | 17500 | "2020-08-01" | "2020-08-31" |
| "Имя1" | "Специалист2" | 19500 | "2020-09-01" | "2020-09-30" |
| "Имя1" | "Специалист2" | 20000 | "2020-10-01" | "9999-12-31" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист1" | 10000 | "2020-01-01" | "2020-01-31" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист1" | 12500 | "2020-02-01" | "2020-02-29" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист1" | 13500 | "2020-03-01" | "2020-03-31" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист1" | 16000 | "2020-04-01" | "2020-04-30" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист2" | 17500 | "2020-05-01" | "2020-05-31" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист2" | 20000 | "2020-06-01" | "2020-06-30" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист2" | 22000 | "2020-07-01" | "2020-07-31" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист1" | 23500 | "2020-08-01" | "2020-08-31" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист1" | 26000 | "2020-09-01" | "2020-09-30" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист1" | 27500 | "2020-10-01" | "2020-10-31" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист1" | 28500 | "2020-11-01" | "2020-11-30" |
| "Имя2" | "Специалист1" | 29500 | "2020-12-01" | "9999-12-31" |
| "Имя3" | "Специалист1" | 10000 | "2020-01-01" | "2020-01-31" |
| "Имя3" | "Специалист1" | 11500 | "2020-02-01" | "2020-02-29" |
| "Имя3" | "Специалист1" | 13000 | "2020-03-01" | "2020-03-31" |
| "Имя3" | "Специалист1" | 14500 | "2020-04-01" | "2020-04-30" |
| "Имя3" | "Специалист2" | 17000 | "2020-05-01" | "2020-05-31" |
| "Имя3" | "Специалист2" | 18500 | "2020-06-01" | "2020-06-30" |
| "Имя3" | "Специалист2" | 19000 | "2020-07-01" | "2020-07-31" |
| "Имя3" | "Специалист2" | 20500 | "2020-08-01" | "2020-08-31" |
| "Имя3" | "Специалист2" | 23000 | "2020-09-01" | "2020-09-30" |
| "Имя3" | "Специалист2" | 25000 | "2020-10-01" | "9999-12-31" |

И вторая sch.t2:

| "date" | "name" | "pay" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "2020-01-07" | "Имя1" | 2000 |
| "2020-01-14" | "Имя1" | 2000 |
| "2020-01-21" | "Имя1" | 2500 |
| "2020-01-31" | "Имя1" | 3500 |
| "2020-02-07" | "Имя1" | 2000 |
| "2020-02-14" | "Имя1" | 3000 |
| "2020-02-21" | "Имя1" | 3000 |
| "2020-02-29" | "Имя1" | 4000 |
| "2020-03-07" | "Имя1" | 2500 |
| "2020-03-14" | "Имя1" | 3000 |
| "2020-03-21" | "Имя1" | 2000 |
| "2020-03-31" | "Имя1" | 6000 |
| "2020-04-07" | "Имя1" | 3500 |
| "2020-04-14" | "Имя1" | 2000 |
| "2020-04-21" | "Имя1" | 3500 |
| "2020-04-30" | "Имя1" | 6000 |
| "2020-05-07" | "Имя1" | 3500 |
| "2020-05-14" | "Имя1" | 2000 |
| "2020-05-21" | "Имя1" | 2500 |
| "2020-05-31" | "Имя1" | 7500 |
| "2020-06-07" | "Имя1" | 2500 |
| "2020-06-14" | "Имя1" | 2500 |
| "2020-06-21" | "Имя1" | 3500 |
| "2020-06-30" | "Имя1" | 7500 |
| "2020-07-07" | "Имя1" | 3500 |
| "2020-07-14" | "Имя1" | 4000 |
| "2020-07-21" | "Имя1" | 2000 |
| "2020-07-31" | "Имя1" | 7500 |
| "2020-08-07" | "Имя1" | 3000 |
| "2020-08-14" | "Имя1" | 2500 |
| "2020-08-21" | "Имя1" | 3000 |
| "2020-08-31" | "Имя1" | 9000 |
| "2020-09-07" | "Имя1" | 4000 |
| "2020-09-14" | "Имя1" | 2000 |
| "2020-09-21" | "Имя1" | 2500 |
| "2020-09-30" | "Имя1" | 11000 |
| "2020-10-07" | "Имя1" | 4000 |
| "2020-10-14" | "Имя1" | 4500 |
| "2020-10-21" | "Имя1" | 5000 |
| "2020-10-31" | "Имя1" | 6500 |
| "2020-11-07" | "Имя1" | 4500 |
| "2020-11-14" | "Имя1" | 5000 |
| "2020-11-21" | "Имя1" | 2000 |
| "2020-11-30" | "Имя1" | 8500 |
| "2020-12-07" | "Имя1" | 3000 |
| "2020-12-14" | "Имя1" | 4000 |
| "2020-12-21" | "Имя1" | 2500 |
| "2020-12-31" | "Имя1" | 10500 |
| "2020-01-07" | "Имя2" | 2500 |
| "2020-01-14" | "Имя2" | 2000 |
| "2020-01-21" | "Имя2" | 2500 |
| "2020-01-31" | "Имя2" | 3000 |
| "2020-02-07" | "Имя2" | 2000 |
| "2020-02-14" | "Имя2" | 2000 |
| "2020-02-21" | "Имя2" | 2500 |
| "2020-02-29" | "Имя2" | 6000 |
| "2020-03-07" | "Имя2" | 3000 |
| "2020-03-14" | "Имя2" | 2500 |
| "2020-03-21" | "Имя2" | 2000 |
| "2020-03-31" | "Имя2" | 6000 |
| "2020-04-07" | "Имя2" | 3000 |
| "2020-04-14" | "Имя2" | 3500 |
| "2020-04-21" | "Имя2" | 4000 |
| "2020-04-30" | "Имя2" | 5500 |
| "2020-05-07" | "Имя2" | 2000 |
| "2020-05-14" | "Имя2" | 3500 |
| "2020-05-21" | "Имя2" | 4000 |
| "2020-05-31" | "Имя2" | 8000 |
| "2020-06-07" | "Имя2" | 4000 |
| "2020-06-14" | "Имя2" | 2500 |
| "2020-06-21" | "Имя2" | 3000 |
| "2020-06-30" | "Имя2" | 10500 |
| "2020-07-07" | "Имя2" | 5000 |
| "2020-07-14" | "Имя2" | 4500 |
| "2020-07-21" | "Имя2" | 5500 |
| "2020-07-31" | "Имя2" | 7000 |
| "2020-08-07" | "Имя2" | 5500 |
| "2020-08-14" | "Имя2" | 3000 |
| "2020-08-21" | "Имя2" | 2000 |
| "2020-08-31" | "Имя2" | 13000 |
| "2020-09-07" | "Имя2" | 3500 |
| "2020-09-14" | "Имя2" | 3000 |
| "2020-09-21" | "Имя2" | 5000 |
| "2020-09-30" | "Имя2" | 14500 |
| "2020-10-07" | "Имя2" | 6000 |
| "2020-10-14" | "Имя2" | 3500 |
| "2020-10-21" | "Имя2" | 4000 |
| "2020-10-31" | "Имя2" | 14000 |
| "2020-11-07" | "Имя2" | 3500 |
| "2020-11-14" | "Имя2" | 7000 |
| "2020-11-21" | "Имя2" | 5500 |
| "2020-11-30" | "Имя2" | 12500 |
| "2020-12-07" | "Имя2" | 4500 |
| "2020-12-14" | "Имя2" | 3000 |
| "2020-12-21" | "Имя2" | 6500 |
| "2020-12-31" | "Имя2" | 15500 |
| "2020-01-07" | "Имя3" | 2000 |
| "2020-01-14" | "Имя3" | 2500 |
| "2020-01-21" | "Имя3" | 2000 |
| "2020-01-31" | "Имя3" | 3500 |
| "2020-02-07" | "Имя3" | 2500 |
| "2020-02-14" | "Имя3" | 2000 |
| "2020-02-21" | "Имя3" | 2500 |
| "2020-02-29" | "Имя3" | 4500 |
| "2020-03-07" | "Имя3" | 2000 |
| "2020-03-14" | "Имя3" | 2500 |
| "2020-03-21" | "Имя3" | 2500 |
| "2020-03-31" | "Имя3" | 6000 |
| "2020-04-07" | "Имя3" | 3500 |
| "2020-04-14" | "Имя3" | 3000 |
| "2020-04-21" | "Имя3" | 3500 |
| "2020-04-30" | "Имя3" | 4500 |
| "2020-05-07" | "Имя3" | 3500 |
| "2020-05-14" | "Имя3" | 2500 |
| "2020-05-21" | "Имя3" | 3500 |
| "2020-05-31" | "Имя3" | 7500 |
| "2020-06-07" | "Имя3" | 4500 |
| "2020-06-14" | "Имя3" | 3500 |
| "2020-06-21" | "Имя3" | 4000 |
| "2020-06-30" | "Имя3" | 6500 |
| "2020-07-07" | "Имя3" | 3500 |
| "2020-07-14" | "Имя3" | 3500 |
| "2020-07-21" | "Имя3" | 2500 |
| "2020-07-31" | "Имя3" | 9500 |
| "2020-08-07" | "Имя3" | 2000 |
| "2020-08-14" | "Имя3" | 2000 |
| "2020-08-21" | "Имя3" | 2000 |
| "2020-08-31" | "Имя3" | 14500 |
| "2020-09-07" | "Имя3" | 5000 |
| "2020-09-14" | "Имя3" | 2000 |
| "2020-09-21" | "Имя3" | 2500 |
| "2020-09-30" | "Имя3" | 13500 |
| "2020-10-07" | "Имя3" | 6000 |
| "2020-10-14" | "Имя3" | 3000 |
| "2020-10-21" | "Имя3" | 4500 |
| "2020-10-31" | "Имя3" | 11500 |
| "2020-11-07" | "Имя3" | 5000 |
| "2020-11-14" | "Имя3" | 5000 |
| "2020-11-21" | "Имя3" | 4500 |
| "2020-11-30" | "Имя3" | 10500 |
| "2020-12-07" | "Имя3" | 5000 |
| "2020-12-14" | "Имя3" | 6000 |
| "2020-12-21" | "Имя3" | 3500 |
| "2020-12-31" | "Имя3" | 10500 |

Как мне объединить эти таблицы? и добавить еще один столбец  "осталось выплатить за месяц"?
Я написал такой код:

```
select 
    --*
    dsp.date,
    dgsh.name,
    dgsh.sal,
    dsp.payt,
    dgsh.from,
    dgsh.to
from sch.t1 as dgsh
inner join sch.t2 as dsp
    on dgsh.name = dsp.name
```

но мне выдает не верные данные, так как в столбцах date, from, to соединяется например так (Всю таблицу отобразить не могу, так как слишком много строк):

|"date"|"name"|"sal"|"pay"|"from"|"to"|
| ---- | ---- | --- | --- | ---- | -- |
|"2020-01-07"|"Имя1"|20000|2000|"2020-10-01"|"9999-12-31"|
|"2020-01-07"|"Имя1"|19500|2000|"2020-09-01"|"2020-09-30"|
|"2020-01-07"|"Имя1"|17500|2000|"2020-08-01"|"2020-08-31"|
|"2020-01-07"|"Имя1"|17000|2000|"2020-07-01"|"2020-07-31"|
|"2020-01-07"|"Имя1"|16000|2000|"2020-06-01"|"2020-06-30"|
|"2020-01-07"|"Имя1"|15500|2000|"2020-05-01"|"2020-05-31"|
|"2020-01-07"|"Имя1"|15000|2000|"2020-04-01"|"2020-04-30"|
|"2020-01-07"|"Имя1"|13500|2000|"2020-03-01"|"2020-03-31"|
|"2020-01-07"|"Имя1"|12000|2000|"2020-02-01"|"2020-02-29"|
|"2020-01-07"|"Имя1"|10000|2000|"2020-01-01"|"2020-01-31"|
|"..."|"..."|...|...|"..."|"..."|
Это не правильно, так как date не входит в пределы from и to. как решить эту проблему? ия не знаю как мне в этой таблице добавить столбец с остатком выплаты на месяц

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно в join добавить, чтоб дата выдачи была в нужном промежутке и сгруппировать данные. Попробуйте так:

```
select t1.name,t1.spec,t1.sal,t1.from,t1.to,sum(t2.pay) as pay,t1.sal-sum(t2.pay) as topay
from t1
     inner join t2 on t1.name=t2.name and t2.date between t1.from and t1.to
group by t1.name,t1.spec,t1.sal,t1.from,t1.to
```